# Why I have this warning?

Tags: postgresql, maven, eclipse

I have an Eclipse maven Web Dynamic Project using Postgres. After pulling from git, I got it locally.I installed Postgres on my Ubuntu 14.04 and with pgAdmin I manage to make everything work. Postgres is written on pom.xml as a dependency and I successfully manage to insert new data on my DB using my project. Although, I got this Eclipse error:

```
Problem with driver "IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ (JDBC 4.0) Default." (Error: Unable to locate JAR/zip in file system as specified by the driver definition: C.)           IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ (JDBC 4.0) Default Driver Problems
```

Even with everything working, anyone knows how to remove this? Update project at Maven didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the the target .jar (like db2jcc.jar / db2jcc4.jar) file exists and is in your library path. When on the dialog for picking the driver .jar, simply click the find jar/zip button and find the file. Sometimes it is detected, but still does not work. If this happens, press the "clear all" button. Now repeat the above process. The .jar will be added and you will continue to driver connection and details dialog box.

Comment: But shouldn't Maven get rid of this for me? Without it I would have to add .jar files every time I move my project to a different machine. I'm trying using Maven to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Should of...but it's bugged in this specific case.